# CentOS 7 Using samba to connect to a windows share at boot

Tags: centos, samba

I'm trying to get a CentOS7 host to mount a directory shared on a Windows 2012 R2 server whenever the host boots.

I have shared the directory to "Everyone" and other windows systems are mapping it

I installed smb-client, samba-common and cifs utils:

```
sudo yum install samba-client samba-common cifs-utils
```

I added the following line to the `/etc/fstab` file:

```
\\ServerIP\share /mnt/share cifs user,uid=500,rw,suid,username=administrator,password=password 0 0
```

samba client is responsive to CLI commands:

```
#smbclient -V outputs
Version 4.4.4
```

Is there a log file somewhere that i can look at to see what samba is doing when I boot?

I am not attempting to host a share on the CentOS device for the windows systems to connect to.

Comment: That should probably be `//<serverIp>/share`

Comment: there are a few guides out there that indicated to use the \\serverIP\.  I changed it over to //serverIP/share/, no change in symptoms.

Comment: Also attempted smbclient -L //serverIP/share -U username.  Error message was NT-STATUS_IO_TIMEOUT.  Everything I lookup online for this says to enable DNS and WINS for name resolution, but i'm attempting to connect by IP.

Comment: That last comment makes it seem as though your issue is similar to that described in [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/132046/unable-to-connect-to-the-samba-server).

Answer (score 0):

1. Check your samba logs under /var/logs/samba
2. If your firewall is up make sure sharing services is allowed or you may turn the firewall off